# linker command failed with exit code 1 Firebase iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I'm trying to put some Firebase pods into my application and I got this error when trying to build it. I've tried cleaning my code and using a different sim, but its still not fixing it. I hope that one of you can point me in the right direction to fix this. It worked smoothly right before I installed these pods :-/
[My Podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCvyZ.png)

```
Ld /Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExteriorBuildingProducts.app/ExteriorBuildingProducts normal x86_64
    cd /Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk -L/Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks/frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks -F/Users/DAW/Desktop/ExteriorBuildingProducts/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks -filelist /Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Intermediates/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ExteriorBuildingProducts.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Intermediates/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ExteriorBuildingProducts_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Intermediates/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ExteriorBuildingProducts.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AdSupport -framework AddressBook -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseStorage -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework GoogleNetworkingUtilities -framework GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleUtilities -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Pods_ExteriorBuildingProducts -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Intermediates/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExteriorBuildingProducts.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ExteriorBuildingProducts_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/DAW/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ExteriorBuildingProducts-hizhkwodsaswcsbishxbptsdpqgv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ExteriorBuildingProducts.app/ExteriorBuildingProducts

ld: framework not found Pods_ExteriorBuildingProducts
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: The code worked fine before I made a podfile put Firebase/Database, Firebase/Auth, and Firebase/Storage

Comment: Show your podfile